# Prevent user to leave page without the confirmation

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have found on StackOverflow this script that handles the issue when a user wants to leave the page, to ask him before doing it.

**ISSUE**

It is working fine (even though there is probably a much better solution) but I have realized that it is causing one "bug". When a user sends data from the form and the script asks him does he want to leave the page (because of the redirect) it still sends data. So, even if the user clicks on "Cancel" it will still proceed to the store() method and if the user adds something more and sends again the data I get duplicates. Is there a way to include "stop propagation" in this script?

**CODE**

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return 'Are you sure you want to close this website?';
    };
```

**Additional question**

Since this script is running with the Laravel Livewire, every time I click on any button related to the livewire (which won't redirect the user to the other page) script prompts the popup to ask if the user is sure he wants to leave the page. Is there any workaround (if you need some other code, write a comment because I am not sure which part could help you at all :) ) for this issue?

Comment: you have to find a way to cancel request if user click on `yes` to leave page.

Comment: which mediator you use to call api for data.

Comment: Please don't ask a user to confirm their navigations, it's really really really irritating. Instead, if you need to save some information, send a silent [beacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) message to your server when a user is about to leave a page.

Comment: @Teemu hi, I know what you are saying but this one is not for the users, it is more like a tool for colleagues and sometimes they cancel the wrong window before the change save. I hate popups too, trust me hahahahah

Comment: @MohitSharma I don't understand what you want to say :/

Comment: That's exactly what the beacon is for. Send the data to your server, and save it, you don't have to bother the user with a save button at all.

Comment: @Teemu well, the solution sounds good. If nobody offers a "direct" answer to my issue, I will definitely try to implement beacons :D Sounds fun, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <script>
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Sure?';
};
</script>
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/yWs7P/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and sorry for the late response. I have some document downloads on the page and they do not leave the page after the download, but this script gets fired anyways. Is there a way to prevent it from firing in that case?